# Removing a combination from a list given criteria (Python)

Tags: python, loops, probability, python-itertools, combinatorics

I have a problem whereby if I have a list as follows.

1. I compare in a pairwise manner (I.e. ["R",1], ["A",1]) if both share the same number but different letter.
2. I generate a probability: either 1, or both are removed from the list.
3. If any or both are removed, I want to make sure that I don't iterate over a pair wise combination that has been previously removed. For eg. if I remove a_list[1], then the pair a_list[1] and a_list[4] can never be considered.

a_list = [["R",1], ["A",1], ["R",2], ["A",2], ["R", 1]]

Note that the context of this problem is to simulate a species simulation if two different species are in the same location (indicated by 1), then they either die or stay alive.

Another example of what I want:
If I set the rule that I kill the second person in the pair, then for each combination of (["R",1], **["A",1]**), (["A",1], **["R", 1]** ), (["R",2], **["A",2]**) >> then I kill what's been **bolded**. But ideally we don't even consider the second pair as [A, 1] was killed anyways in that first combo.

Many thanks!

My thinking is to add some **continue** line if the element has been removed from the original list however in the case below, I get the error: "list.remove(x): x not in list"

This is what I have tried so far:

```
a_list = [["R",1], ["A",1], ["R",2], ["S",2], ["R", 1]]


for a, b in itertools.combinations(a_list[:], 2):
    if a[0]!=b[0] and a[1]==b[1]:
        print(a,b)
        a_prob=np.random.choice([0,1], p=[0.5,0.5])
        b_prob=np.random.choice([0,1], p=[0.5,0.5])
        if a_prob==1:
            print("a alive",a_prob)
        else:
            if a_prob==0: 
                a_list.remove(a)
                print("a dead",a_prob)
                
        
        if b_prob==1:
            print("b alive",b_prob)
        else:
            if b_prob==0: 
                a_list.remove(b)
                print("b dead",b_prob)
```

Comment: So, for `a_list = [["R",1], ["A",1], ["R",2], ["A",2], ["R", 1]]`, what is your expected outcome?

Comment: I've written a lot of code which is similar in flavor to the example you posted. Based on my experience, my pretty strong advice is to proceed by steps, transforming your data in one way at a time, looking at the result at each step. In this case I might do something like: construct mask to mark the items of interest; for every element in mask, generate probability (0 if element is not interesting); construct "what to do" array from probability array; apply the what-to-do array to the original list.

Comment: At each step, look at the intermediate result. There may be more efficient schemes, but first and foremost you must ensure you are getting a correct result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem with your code is that it is not updating the `itertools.combinations(a_list[:], 2)` so once you delete a value you can still iterate over a different combination containing that value

I have enumerated your original list (since a value can occur more than once like `["R", 1]`) and then created a list for `itertools.combinations(a_list[:], 2)` and also created a function to properly delete a value from that list

```
a_list = [["R", 1], ["A", 1], ["R", 2], ["S", 2], ["R", 1]]
a_list_2 = list(enumerate(a_list))
a_combinations = list(itertools.combinations(a_list_2, 2))


def a_remove_element(x):
    for i in a_combinations[:]:
        if i[0][0] == x or i[1][0] == x:
            a_combinations.remove(i)


for a, b in a_combinations:
    if a[1][0] != b[1][0] and a[1][1] == b[1][1]:
        print(a, b)
        a_prob, b_prob = np.random.choice([0, 1], size=2)
        if a_prob:
            print("a alive", a_prob)
        else:
            a_remove_element(a[0])
            print("a dead", a_prob)

        if b_prob:
            print("b alive", b_prob)
        else:
            a_remove_element(b[0])
            print("b dead", b_prob)
```

Comment: Hey! I really appreciate ur time and response but not quite what I was after. This si more of a concrete eg of what Im after:  If I set the rule that I kill the second person in the pair, then for each combination of (["R",1], **["A",1]**), (["A",1], **["R", 1]** ), (["R",2], **["A",2]**) >> then I kill what's been **bolded.** But ideally, we don't even consider the second pair as [A, 1] was killed anyways in that first combo.

Comment: I tried your code for this example and it seemed to be slightly buggy: [["A", 1], ["R", 1], ["R", 2], ["S", 2], ["R", 1],["A", 1]]

Comment: do you mean when we kill ["A", 1] we will kill all the ["A", 1]'s in the list?

Comment: Hey, thanks for getting back to me again! No not quite. Speaking in terms of index terms, if a_list[1] is removed/ killed, then I should ignore all other pairs that would involve this i.e. a pair of a_list[1] and a_list[4]. I believe your original code worked for the first list but it didn't work when i changed it slightly to [["A", 1], ["R", 1], ["R", 2], ["S", 2], ["R", 1],["A", 1]]

Comment: I have made a small edit to my code, it should work now.

Comment: if you found this (or any other answer on stack overflow) useful you could upvote it and press on the tick next to it, this will also increase your reputation and hence give you more privileges on stack overflow. not a force though I just said it since you are a new user